# Takes images from gallery

Tags: android

My app takes images from gallery and copies to a subfolder. But, the images that are copied are comes to gallery as a copy of original one from different location.

How to prevent it? please help me.

this is my code to save to a pre defined folder....

```
protected String saveBitmap(Bitmap bm, String path) throws Exception {
    String tempFilePath="/sdcard/AuFridis/Events/Images/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"myEventImg.jpg";
    File tempFile = new File(path+"/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"myEventImg.jpg");
   // File tempFile = new File("/sdcard/Notes");
    tempFile.createNewFile();

    if (!tempFile.exists()) {
        if (!tempFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
            tempFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }
    }

    //tempFile.delete();
    //tempFile.createNewFile();

    int quality = 100;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);

    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
    bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, bos);

    bos.flush();
    bos.close();

    //bm.recycle();
    Log.i("On saveBitmap Function - retrieved file path", "---"+tempFilePath);
    return tempFilePath;

}
```

Comment: so now in the gallery u see the image twice? one the original, and the other one is the one copied by ur app?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to hide the images from the gallery? Android by default scans the memory of the device and puts all photos it finds into the gallery. The device is most likely seeing the repeated name and labeling. Just change the image name.

Answer (score 0):

By default, android scans the SD card and adds all images it finds to the gallery.  If you copy an image from gallery to another folder, that folder will automatically be added to the gallery.  To prevent this, add an empty file with name `.nomedia` to your destination folder - and your copied images will not show in the gallery.

Comment: Can u explain it a bit more.. plz.. wats this .nomedia??

Comment: android scans SD card every time its content changes and automatically adds to the gallery every image and video it finds. An app can choose to prevent its media from being indexed/added - if android sees in the folder a file named `.nomedia`, then it skips that folder and images and videos from that folder will not be scanned/indexed/added to gallery.